# Group together duplicates in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am making a query to see how much stock gets booked into our warehouse, how do I group together all the duplicates so all the quantities can be as one and the same product isn't showing multiple times? I will post a screenshot to show what I get and the code I'm using.
Thanks

[Duplicates example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zWeW.png)

```
select b.qty, a.part, a.desc1, a.main_supplier as supplier_acc_no, c.name as 
 supplier_name, a.main_mpn, a.date_receipt as date_booked_in
from public.stock as a
inner JOIN public.sthist AS b ON a.part = b.part
inner join public.supplier as c on a.main_supplier = c.account
where a.date_receipt > date_trunc('day', CURRENT_DATE) - INTERVAL '2 days'
and b.tran_type = 'POGRN'
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `group by` with `sum` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sum and group by (and appropriate functions for any non-group-by expressions). e.g.,

```
select sum(b.qty), a.part, min(a.desc1), 
min(a.main_supplier) as supplier_acc_no, min(c.name) as supplier_name, 
min(a.main_mpn), min(a.date_receipt) as date_booked_in
from public.stock as a
inner JOIN public.sthist AS b ON a.part = b.part
inner join public.supplier as c on a.main_supplier = c.account
where a.date_receipt > date_trunc('day', CURRENT_DATE) - INTERVAL '2 days'
and b.tran_type = 'POGRN'
group by a.part
```